# Query XML in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, xquery

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE tab_customerxml 
(
    id INT IDENTITY, 
    xmldata XML
)
```

and I loaded an xml with insert.

I want to run this simple query

```
SELECT 
    xmldata.query('/customer')
FROM 
    tab_customerxml 
WHERE 
    id = 4;
```

but I get this error:

> Can not run because select the settings of the following SET options are incorrect QUOTED_IDENTIFIER.

I do not know how to solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Side note: since your `id` column is of type `int`, you should use this notation in your `WHERE` clause: `WHERE id = 4` - don't add those unnecessary single quotes - this makes our `'4'` a string, which has to be implicitly converted back to an `Int` ..... if it's an `int` - don't use any single quotes to begin with

Comment: I changed where id = 4 but does not work the same @marc_s

Comment: also  without where statement , I always get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this:

- drop your table

  ```
  DROP TABLE tab_customerxml;
  ```
- re-create it with the proper settings on:

  ```
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  SET ANSI_PADDING ON

  CREATE TABLE tab_customerxml 
  (
     id INT IDENTITY, 
     xmldata XML
  )
  ```
- now try your query again

  ```
  SELECT xmldata.query('/customer')
  FROM tab_customerxml 
  WHERE id = 4;
  ```

Does that help?

Comment: thanks it works. but I did not understand what was the problem

Comment: @Genny: as the error clearly says: the setting for `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` was wrong. Not sure why - but adding these three `SET .... ON` lines before creating your table works for me